# How to install my app for all device users when it is installed by Owner user?

Tags: android, android-multiple-users

I would like to know how to make the app and his services available for all device users, including guest mode and users added after it's installation. Kiosk mode and root the device are not an option. 
My app runs with admin permissions. The APK is installed directly by the user, and not through Play Store. It has 3 services running in the background. It works on Lollipop onwards.
Is it possible to do this?